# SQL. Как поменять текстовые данные на числовые, чтобы посчитать сумму?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Подскажите, плиз, как поменять данные, представленные в форматированном текстовом виде ($100.00) на числовые, чтобы посчитать сумму?
Подскажите, как написать правильный код в SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так : `CAST(Replace('$100.00','$','') as FLOAT)`

Вот на примере запроса к абстрактной таблице:

```
Select SUM(CAST(Replace(Value,'$','') as FLOAT)) from Table
```